# code without error but result false

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote program .. the user must enter a string with format (Barcode,price:number of item)
and I calculate the total of barcode

my code is

```
import java.util.*;

public class hanoofee2 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string with format (Barcode,price:number of item) ");
        String ent = input.nextLine();
        String barcode = ent.substring(0,(ent.indexOf(",")));
        String price = ent.substring((ent.indexOf(","))+1,(ent.indexOf(":")));
        String number = ent.substring(ent.indexOf(":")+1,(ent.length()));

        double price2 = Double.parseDouble(price);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(number);
        double total = price2 * number2;

        String m = "";
        if(barcode == "11A") {
            m ="green pen";
        } else if(barcode == "22B") {
            m ="printer";
        } else if(barcode == "44C") {
            m ="Memory card";
        } else if(barcode == "44D") {
            m ="Cook book";
        }

        System.out.printf("The total price of%2s "+" is:%.2f ", m ,total);
    }
}
```

every things are ok
but when I press run
the value of " m" does not display

```
     Enter a string with format (Barcode,price:number of item) 
       22B,222:30
       The total price of    is:6660.00 
        ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

what is the problem ?!

Comment: Please take the time to format your code readably when asking for help.

Comment: I could not agree more with @T.J.Crowder: people are here to help you, free of charge. So be kind towards their eyes and their time! This time I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> every things are ok but when I press run the value of " m" does not display

Don't use `==` to compare content of String.

Use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

[Why should I use equals() instead of == ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513846)